# How to hide SFSafariViewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller

SFSafariViewController allows a webpage to access cookie stored in Safari. I would like to perform some background task with SFSafariViewController to utilize the cookie. However I do not want the user to see the SFSafariViewController.

Is there a way to hide SFSafariViewController and allow user to touch the screen when SFSafariViewController is presented?

Answer (score 2):

```
Class SFSafariViewControllerClass = NSClassFromString(@"SFSafariViewController");
if (SFSafariViewControllerClass) {
    id safController = [[SFSafariViewControllerClass alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

    UIViewController *windowRootController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    self.secondWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    self.secondWindow.rootViewController = windowRootController;
    [self.secondWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self.secondWindow setAlpha:0];

    [windowRootController presentViewController:safController animated:YES completion:^{
        [self.secondWindow.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NULL];
    }];
}
```

you can use the code to hide the SFSafariViewControllerClass

Comment: setting the alpha to zero no longer works in iOS 10. You can set the main window.windowLevel to a high number, then set it back to 0.

Comment: @Away Lin did u face any rejection of your app while submitting? I am asking this since the usage of SFSafariViewControllerClass in the answer will violate the legal point as pointed out in the second answer

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this if you're planning to submit to the App Store.

From https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/:

> 5.1.1 (iv) SafariViewContoller must be used to visibly present information to users; the controller may not be hidden or obscured by
>   other views or layers. Additionally, an app may not use
>   SafariViewController to track users without their knowledge and
>   consent.

If you need to access cookies, use WKWebView instead. See [Getting all cookies from WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33156567/getting-all-cookies-from-wkwebview). These cookies aren't shared with Safari, though.