# How to share cookies set in response in WKWebview with further dataTaskWithRequests

Tags: cookies, nsurlsession, wkwebview

I'm trying to set cookies on a dataTask on `NSURLSession.sharedSession()`, obtained from a webpage in a WKWebView instance.

Somehow when reading the cookies from `NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()` after visiting the webpage with cookies set from the server, I'm not always getting the cookies the first attempt reading them. It seems that WKWebView uses some background proces/scheduling for persisting the cookies... anybody with experience/best practices/workaround for this, or maybe I'm just doing it wrong?

Comment: Anyone facing the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33156567/getting-all-cookies-from-wkwebview helped me for now.