# User Agent change at run time

Tags: swift, uiwebview, swift2

I'm trying to add mobile, desktop version site functionality on my app. But the problem is that `User Agent` only change at once before webView loading. In my app i add to button one for `Mobile` and second for `Desktop` version site. `UIWebView` pick `User Agent` just on start.Can anyone tell me is there any way to change `User Agent` at run time. Thanks

```
 var defaultUserAgent = String()
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        webView.loadRequest(request)
    }

    @IBAction func mobile(sender: AnyObject) {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(["UserAgent": defaultUserAgent])
        print(defaultUserAgent)

        let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        webView.loadRequest(request)

    }

    @IBAction func desktop(sender: AnyObject) {

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(["UserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36"])

        let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        webView.loadRequest(request)

    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        print(webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("navigator.userAgent"))
        defaultUserAgent = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("navigator.userAgent")!
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you to use *[WkWebView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview)* instead of *UIWebView* as it is comparatively more powerfull

WkWebView of iOS 9 has a direct API

```
 if #available(iOS 9, *) {
            webViewObj.customUserAgent = "customUserAgentValue"
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @Durai Amuthan.H I know about this, but due to some reasons i need to use `UIWebView`. Is there any way to achieve this? I'v seen one iOS app that give us same functionality also in iOS 7.

Comment: Basically i need to get and save cookies from webView, I can easily get cookies from `UIWebView`, but too complicated if i use `WkWebView`, like acording to [Stefan Arentz](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33156567/getting-all-cookies-from-wkwebview). Thats reason why i am using `UIWebView`

Comment: I don't think its complicated in WkWebView.In fact WkWebView provides easy interface to take advantage of WebKit.The learning curve is steep that's all.

Comment: I don't know if the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26577303/730807) is related but thought like sharing