# WKWebView Persistent Storage of Cookies

Tags: ios, cookies, wkwebview

I am using a `WKWebView` in my native iPhone application, on a website that allows login/registration, and stores the session information in cookies.   I am trying to figure out how to persistently store the cookie information, so when the app restarts, the user still has their web session available.

I have 2 `WKWebViews` in the app, and they share a `WKProcessPool`.  I start with a shared process pool:

`WKProcessPool *processPool = [[WKProcessPool alloc] init];`

Then for each WKWebView:

```
WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init]; 
theConfiguration.processPool = processPool; 
self.webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame configuration:theConfiguration];
```

When I log in using the first `WKWebView`, and then some time later pass the action to the 2nd `WKWebView`, the session is retained, so the cookies were successfully shared.  However, when I relaunch the app, a new process pool is created and the session information is destroyed.  Is there any way to get the session information to persist through an app restart?

Comment: You don't need to do additional actions to save `WKWebView` data - it should be saved automatically (the only thing that need be clarified is that you are using `defaultDataStore` in configuration, because it is only one that is saved to disk). Are you sure that the session info lost in `WKWebView`? Is it possible that the cookies has small ttl or something else? Did you check this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is actually a tough one because there's a) some [bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=140191) that's still not solved by Apple (I think) and b) depends on what cookies you want, I think.

I wasn't able to test this now, but I can give you some pointers:

1. Getting cookies from `NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()`. This one seems buggy, apparently the cookies aren't immediately saved for `NSHTTPCookieStorage` to find them. [People](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33156567/710041) suggest to trigger a save by resetting the process pool, but I don't know whether that reliably works. You might want to try that out for yourself, though.
2. The process pool is not really what saves the cookies (though it defines whether they are shared as you correctly stated). The documentation says that's `WKWebsiteDataStore`, so I'd look that up. At least getting the cookies from there using `fetchDataRecordsOfTypes:completionHandler:` might be possible (not sure how to set them, though, and I assume you can't just save the store in user defaults for the same reason as for the process pool).
3. Should you manage to get the cookies you need (or rather their values), but not be able to restore them as I guess will be the case, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26577303/710041) (basically it shows how to simply prepare the httprequest with them already, relevant part: `[request addValue:@"TeskCookieKey1=TeskCookieValue1;TeskCookieKey2=TeskCookieValue2;" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"]`).
4. If all else fails, check [this](https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/WKWebViewTips). I know providing just link only answers is not good, but I can't copy all that and just want to add it for completeness sake.

One last thing in general: I said that your success might also depend on the type of cookie. That's because [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34190447/710041) states that cookies set by the server are not accessible via `NSHTTPCookieStorage`. I don't know whether that's relevant to you (but I guess it is, since you're probably looking for a session, i.e. server-set cookie, correct?) and I don't know whether this means that the other methods fail as well.

If all else fails, you might consider saving the users credentials somewhere (keychain, for example) and reuse them on the next app start to auth automatically. This might not restore all session data, but considering the user quit the app that's maybe actually desirable?
Also perhaps certain values can be caught and saved for later use using an injected script, like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26577303/710041) (obviously not for setting them at start, but maybe retrieve them at some point. You need to know how the site works then, of course).

I hope that could at least point you towards some new directions solving the issue. It's not as trivial as it should be, it seems (then again, session cookies are kind of a security relevant thing, so maybe hiding them away from the App is a conscious design choice by Apple...).

Comment: It looks like I was able to view some cookies eventually in NSHTTPCookiesStorage, so you were right, maybe just not immediately saved.  However, the cookie needed for the session did not seem to be there, so your last point regarding server-side cookies is possibly what is happening.

Comment: Dang it, that's too bad. I guess then you'll probably have to actively relog in if the app is completely restarted. As long as you store the user's credentials safely somewhere (I suggest the keychain, at least for the password) that should be fine. Not ideal, of course, but that way you could request a new session token with a proper HTTPRequest?

Answer (score 20):

I'm a little late in answering this but I would like to add some insights to the existing answers. The answer mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49651579/1869954) provides valuable information into Cookie Persistence on WKWebView. However, there are a few caveats to it.

1. `WKWebView` doesn't work well with `NSHTTPCookieStorage`, so for iOS
   8, 9, 10 you will have to use UIWebView.
2. You don't need to necessarily hold on to the `WKWebView` as a
   singleton but you do need to use the same instance of
   `WKProcessPool` every time to get the desired cookies again.
3. It is preferable to set the cookies first using the `setCookie`
   method and then instantiate the `WKWebView`.

I would also like to highlight the iOS 11+ Solution in Swift.

```
let urlString = "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
var webView: WKWebView!
let group = DispatchGroup()
    
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setupWebView { [weak self] in
        self?.loadURL()
    }
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.getAllCookies { cookies in
            self.setData(cookies, key: "cookies")
        }
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
}

private func loadURL() {
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!)
    self.webView.load(urlRequest)
}
    
private func setupWebView(_ completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    
    func setup(config: WKWebViewConfiguration) {
        self.webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: config)
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
        self.webView.uiDelegate = self
        self.webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(self.webView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            self.webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
            self.webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
            self.webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor)])
    }
    
    self.configurationForWebView { config in
        setup(config: config)
        completion()
    }
    
}

private func configurationForWebView(_ completion: @escaping (WKWebViewConfiguration) -> Void) {
            
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    
    //Need to reuse the same process pool to achieve cookie persistence
    let processPool: WKProcessPool

    if let pool: WKProcessPool = self.getData(key: "pool")  {
        processPool = pool
    }
    else {
        processPool = WKProcessPool()
        self.setData(processPool, key: "pool")
    }

    configuration.processPool = processPool
    
    if let cookies: [HTTPCookie] = self.getData(key: "cookies") {
        
        for cookie in cookies {
            
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                group.enter()
                configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie(cookie) {
                    print("Set cookie = \(cookie) with name = \(cookie.name)")
                    self.group.leave()
                }
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        completion(configuration)
    }
}
```

Helper methods:

```
func setData(_ value: Any, key: String) {
    let ud = UserDefaults.standard
    let archivedPool = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: value)
    ud.set(archivedPool, forKey: key)
}

func getData<T>(key: String) -> T? {
    let ud = UserDefaults.standard
    if let val = ud.value(forKey: key) as? Data,
        let obj = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: val) as? T {
        return obj
    }
    
    return nil
}
```

Edit:
I had mentioned that it's preferable to instantiate `WKWebView` post `setCookie` calls. I ran into some issues wherein the `setCookie` completion handlers were not getting called the second time I tried to open the `WKWebView`. This seems to a be a bug in the WebKit. Therefore, I had to instantiate `WKWebView` first and then call `setCookie` on the configuration. Make sure to load the URL only after all the `setCookie` calls have returned.

Comment: people looking for solution of complex thing not easy one :) if you have solution for ios 8 till 11 please share...

Answer (score 19):

Finally, I have found a solution to manage sessions in WKWebView, work under swift 4, but the solution can be carried to swift 3 or object-C:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let url = URL(string: "https://insofttransfer.com")!


@IBOutlet weak var webview: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    webview.load(URLRequest(url: self.url))
    webview.uiDelegate = self
    webview.navigationDelegate = self
}}
```

**Create an extension for WKWebview...**

```
extension WKWebView {

enum PrefKey {
    static let cookie = "cookies"
}

func writeDiskCookies(for domain: String, completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    fetchInMemoryCookies(for: domain) { data in
        print("write data", data)
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(data, forKey: PrefKey.cookie + domain)
        completion();
    }
}


 func loadDiskCookies(for domain: String, completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    if let diskCookie = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: (PrefKey.cookie + domain)){
        fetchInMemoryCookies(for: domain) { freshCookie in

            let mergedCookie = diskCookie.merging(freshCookie) { (_, new) in new }

            for (cookieName, cookieConfig) in mergedCookie {
                let cookie = cookieConfig as! Dictionary<String, Any>

                var expire : Any? = nil

                if let expireTime = cookie["Expires"] as? Double{
                    expire = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: expireTime)
                }

                let newCookie = HTTPCookie(properties: [
                    .domain: cookie["Domain"] as Any,
                    .path: cookie["Path"] as Any,
                    .name: cookie["Name"] as Any,
                    .value: cookie["Value"] as Any,
                    .secure: cookie["Secure"] as Any,
                    .expires: expire as Any
                ])

                self.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie(newCookie!)
            }

            completion()
        }

    }
    else{
        completion()
    }
}

func fetchInMemoryCookies(for domain: String, completion: @escaping ([String: Any]) -> ()) {
    var cookieDict = [String: AnyObject]()
    WKWebsiteDataStore.default().httpCookieStore.getAllCookies { (cookies) in
        for cookie in cookies {
            if cookie.domain.contains(domain) {
                cookieDict[cookie.name] = cookie.properties as AnyObject?
            }
        }
        completion(cookieDict)
    }
}}
```

**Then Create an extension for our View Controller Like this**

```
extension ViewController: WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
   //load cookie of current domain
    webView.loadDiskCookies(for: url.host!){
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}

public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
   //write cookie for current domain
    webView.writeDiskCookies(for: url.host!){
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
}
```

Where `url` is current URL:

```
    let url = URL(string: "https://insofttransfer.com")!
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this copy/paste solution!! It worked like a charm!

Comment: Oh man ! Wish I saw this answer earlier. This is the one worked for me after trying many things whole day .

However, I had to change "webView.loadDiskCookies(for: url.host!)" to "webView.writeDiskCookies(for:(webView.url?.host!)!)"

Comment: One note about this solution is that it'e extremely non-performant since you have to read and write to disk via UserDefaults twice for every request.

Answer (score 13):

After days of research and experiments, I have found a solution to manage sessions in WKWebView, This is a work around because I didn’t find any other way to achieve this, below are the steps:

First you need to create methods to set and get data in user defaults, when I say data it means NSData, here are the methods.

```
+(void)saveDataInNSDefault:(id)object key:(NSString *)key{
    NSData *encodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:object];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:encodedObject forKey:key];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

+ (id)getDataFromNSDefaultWithKey:(NSString *)key{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *encodedObject = [defaults objectForKey:key];
    id object = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encodedObject];
    return object;
}
```

For maintaining session on webview I made my webview and WKProcessPool singleton.

```
- (WKWebView *)sharedWebView {
    static WKWebView *singleton;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        WKWebViewConfiguration *webViewConfig = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
        WKUserContentController *controller = [[WKUserContentController alloc] init];

        [controller addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"callNativeAction"];
        [controller addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"callNativeActionWithArgs"];
        webViewConfig.userContentController = controller;
        webViewConfig.processPool = [self sharedWebViewPool];

        singleton = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.vwContentView.frame configuration:webViewConfig];

    });
    return singleton;
}

- (WKProcessPool *)sharedWebViewPool {
    static WKProcessPool *pool;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

        pool = [Helper getDataFromNSDefaultWithKey:@"pool"];

        if (!pool) {
            pool = [[WKProcessPool alloc] init];
        }

    });
    return pool;
}
```

In ViewDidLoad, I check if it’s not the login page and load cookies into HttpCookieStore from User Defaults so It will by pass authentication or use those cookies to maintain session.

```
if (!isLoginPage) {
            [request setValue:accessToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

            NSMutableSet *setOfCookies = [Helper getDataFromNSDefaultWithKey:@"cookies"];
            for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in setOfCookies) {
                if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {

                    [webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore setCookie:cookie completionHandler:^{}];
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                    [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookie];
                }
            }
        }
```

And, Load the request.

Now, we will maintain webview sessions using cookies, so on your login page webview, save cookies from httpCookieStore into user defaults in viewDidDisappear method.

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    if (isLoginPage) { //checking if it’s login page.
        NSMutableSet *setOfCookies = [Helper getDataFromNSDefaultWithKey:@"cookies"]?[Helper getDataFromNSDefaultWithKey:@"cookies"]:[NSMutableArray array];
        //Delete cookies if >50
        if (setOfCookies.count>50) {
            [setOfCookies removeAllObjects];
        }
        if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
            [webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore getAllCookies:^(NSArray<NSHTTPCookie *> * _Nonnull arrCookies) {

                for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in arrCookies) {
                    NSLog(@"Cookie: \n%@ \n\n", cookie);
                    [setOfCookies addObject:cookie];
                }
                [Helper saveDataInNSDefault:setOfCookies key:@"cookies"];
            }];
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            NSArray *cookieStore = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage.cookies;
            for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookieStore) {
                NSLog(@"Cookie: \n%@ \n\n", cookie);
                [setOfCookies addObject:cookie];
            }
            [Helper saveDataInNSDefault:setOfCookies key:@"cookies"];
        }
    }

    [Helper saveDataInNSDefault:[self sharedWebViewPool] key:@"pool"];
}
```

> Note: Above method is tested for iOS 11 only, although I have written
>   fallback for lower versions also but didn’t test those.

Hope this solves your problems !!! :)

Comment: This was the first answer I found that solved this issue (I'm testing with iOS 14).
Thank you very much!

Comment: @bruestle2 Happy to help :)

Comment: Huge "Thank You!!!" for posting this solution! As mentioned above- this is the only ios14 solution I've found in a sea of poorly documented /out of date articles on the subject

Answer (score 9):

After extensive search and manual debug I reached these simple conclusions (iOS11+).

**You need to considerate these two categories:**

- You are using `WKWebsiteDataStore.nonPersistentDataStore`:

  > Then the `WKProcessPool` **does not matter**.
  >
  > 1. Extract cookies using `websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.getAllCookies()`
  > 2. Save these cookies into UserDefaults (or preferably the Keychain).
  > 3. ...
  > 4. Later when you re-create these cookies from storage, call `websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie()` for each cookie and
  >      you're good to go.
- You are using `WKWebsiteDataStore.defaultDataStore`:

  > Then the `WKProcessPool` associated with configuration **DOES
  >   matter**.   It has to be saved along with the cookies.
  >
  > 1. Save the webview configuration's processPool into UserDefaults (or preferably the Keychain).
  > 2. Extract cookies using `websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.getAllCookies()`
  > 3. Save these cookies into UserDefaults (or preferably the Keychain).
  > 4. ...
  > 5. Later re-create the process pool from storage and assign it to the web view's configuration
  > 6. Re-create the cookies from storage and call `websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie()` for each cookie

Note: there are many detailed implementations already available so I keep it simple by not adding more implementation details.

Comment: I empirically just tried and with nonPersistentDataStore the WKProcessPool matters... as long as you use the same nonPersistentDataStore.
Basically, if you want to have a non-persistent store for like incognito mode stuff but that is shared across different WKWebView instances (think tabs of a browser), then you also want to share the same WKProcessPool.

Comment: @txulu thanks for letting me know. It's very possible that things have changed since my answer (a year ago). My answer applied to persisting and then restoring, did you try this use-case? Or did you just try using across multiple WKWebViews? I'm happy to try again and update my answers if things have changed for the use-case I'm describing.

Comment: I tried across multiple, yes. When you have multiple WKWebViews, they have to share the dataStore AND the process pool or cookies won't be shared across. Which makes sense, different processes should not talk to each other for security reasons.

Answer (score 3):

I am a bit late to the party but people might find this useful. There is a workaround, it's a bit annoying but as far as I can say it is the only solution that works reliably, at least until apple fix their dumb APIs...

I've spend a good 3 days trying to get the cached cookies out of the `WKWebView` needless to say that got me nowhere... eventually I've released that I could just get the cookies directly from the server.

The first thing I tried to do is get all the cookies with javascript that was running within the `WKWebView` and then pass them to the `WKUserContentController` where I would just store them to `UserDefaults`. This didn't work since my cookies where `httponly` and apparently you can't get those with javascript...

I've ended up fixing it by inserting a javascript call into the page on the server side (Ruby on Rail in my case) with the cookies as the parameter, e.g.

`sendToDevice("key:value")`

The above js function is simply passing cookies to the device. Hope this will help someone stay sane...

Answer (score -1):

`WKWebView` conforms to `NSCoding` ,so you can use `NSCoder` to decode/encode your webView ,and store it somewhere else ,like `NSUserDefaults`.

```
//return data to store somewhere
NSData* data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.webView];/

self.webView = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Comment: Thanks, but when retrieving the WKWebView from nsuserdefaults after a new app launch, the session information of the website was not retained.

Answer (score -3):

Store the information in `NSUserDefaults`. At the same time if the session information is very critical, it is better to store it in `KeyChain`.

Comment: Store what information in user defaults?  WKProcessPool can't be stored in defaults, there are errors about being able to encode it.