# WKWebView not saving cookies on iOS 11, but works fine on iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I have a `WKWebView` that displays a webpage with login.
After logging in, it saves the cookies and takes the user to his admin panel (again, everything is happening inside the WebView).

When I close the app and re-open, the cookies are not saved and I have to re-login on `iOS 11`.

If I run the app on `iOS 10`, everything works fine and the cookie data is persistent.

Another Issue: Another problem I have, the `WKWebView` on `iOS 11` starts like it's scrolled down (hiding the title of the webpage and I have to scroll to reveal it). On `iOS 10` it works fine.

What happened? did Apple screw up the `WKWebView` object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of 
[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772007/wkwebview-persistent-storage-of-cookies) .

One thing I can share: if you have an iframe inside the WKWebView it CAN NOT create cookies. Let alone keep them. FYI.

AFAIK it's all by design.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. So far, I wonder if Apple's updated policy in regards to third party cookies has something to do with this. I will share if I find any solutions.