# Persist WkWebView Session

Tags: objective-c, wkwebview

I have a server List in Native. When one of the items on the list is clicked, I am using WKWebView to load an URL from item.

Each of the server have their own login session. 
Now when I open one of the server pages in WKWebView and come back to the server list and select the same server again. Instead of using the previous session, it creates a new session for the server. This results in additional license being checked out from the server.

How do I check if there is already a session open and use that session for WKWebView instead of creating a new session every time?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772007/wkwebview-persistent-storage-of-cookies/49651579#49651579