# WKWebview iOS (swift) : Keep session connected after app closed

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, progressive-web-apps

I want to make an app from a PWA on iOS using a simple `WKWebView`. I've managed to implement it in a simple `ViewController` and it is working fine.

**Problem** : when i login and then quit the app, the session is lost and i have to login again.

**Question** : Is it possible to keep the session informations after the user quit the app ?

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into persisting your session data. For `WKWebView`, all of that is part of `WKProcessPool`. So when your app goes into the background, you need to look into persisting the `WKProcessPool` session, and when you use your web view, always use that same `WKProcessPool` instance.

Here's an answer that may help you save that data to your UserDefaults.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52109021/2658489

Comment: I tried to save the pool, which work (the "getData" function return a value) but the session is not kept. Do you suggest something else ?

Comment: @julient-monisnap I would think the process pool has everything from the previous session. Only thing I can imagine is the session was invalidated server side.

Answer (score -3):

I think you should implement login API, for authorization and Login UI on Native App, and then you can have dashboard items using single WKWebView controller.

When a user logged in with the native page - loginViewController, you should store user name, password (maybe encrypted) in user preferences, e,g.

```
 UserDefaults.standard.set(userName, forKey: keyUserName)
 UserDefaults.standard.set(userPassword, forKey: keyPassword)
 UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Next time (after quit App) when you back you can check for auto login in AppDelegate - didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
e.g.

```
if let username = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: keyUserName) as? String,
        password = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: keyPassword) as? String
    {
            /// DO AUTOLOGIN .. CALL API AND LAND TO DASHBOARD PAGE (WKWebView)..
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it does not solve my problem. My issue is that the session cookie of the WKWebView is not saved when i kill the app. I always have to login again.

Comment: This is bad practice. Never store the passwords in client side code.