# Logged in user session not working on WKWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

I am using WKWebView on my app where user can login, but I have an issue. The user credentials are not saved so the user has to login every time he starts the app. I am using sessions to keep user logged in Javascript on my website, but the sessions are not working on WKWebView.

I tried: `request.httpShouldHandleCookies = true` but it is not working.

Comment: Try with appending session id with your UrlRequest.
I have similar kind of functionality and it works for me.

Comment: Did you find a way to work this out?

Answer (score 0):

You options:

1. You can either pass an auth token, like many do
2. Use `WKProcessPool`: [WKWebview iOS (swift) : Keep session connected after app closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53282119/wkwebview-ios-swift-keep-session-connected-after-app-closed)
3. Another possible option is to share sessions with Safari using
   `SFSafariViewController` (but then you can't access the content of
   the page)