# How to fetch cookies from WKWebView for iOS 10 and below?

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I have tried following approaches to fetch the cookies from  `WKWebView` in iOS 10 and below  and not able to get the cookies:

1: Fetching cookies from HTTPCookieStorage.
2: Fetching the cookies form WKNavigationResponse model once the loading is completed.
3: Fetching from WKUserContentController by adding observers for cookie changes using WKUserScript.

Comment: Have you find any solution? i have same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WKWebsiteDataStore.default().httpCookieStore
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebsitedatastore

For Objective-C you can try:

```
- (void)clearCookies {
  NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
  for (NSHTTPCookie *c in cookieStorage.cookies) {
    [cookieStorage deleteCookie:c];
  }
}

- (void)clearWKData {
  NSSet *cachedData = [NSSet setWithArray:@[
    WKWebsiteDataTypeCookies,
    WKWebsiteDataTypeDiskCache,
    WKWebsiteDataTypeMemoryCache,
    WKWebsiteDataTypeLocalStorage,
    WKWebsiteDataTypeSessionStorage,
    WKWebsiteDataTypeWebSQLDatabases,
    WKWebsiteDataTypeIndexedDBDatabases,
    WKWebsiteDataTypeOfflineWebApplicationCache,
  ]];

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSDate *epoch = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];
    [[WKWebsiteDataStore defaultDataStore] removeDataOfTypes:cachedData modifiedSince:epoch completionHandler:^{}];
    [[WKWebsiteDataStore defaultDataStore] removeDataOfTypes:cachedData modifiedSince:epoch completionHandler:^{
      // Completion
    }];
  });
}
```

Comment: httpCookieStore is available from iOS 11. I need to save the cookies for iOS 10

Comment: @VinayKiran aight let me get ya’ll 2morrow

Comment: @CyberMew here is something I use, but it is in Objective-C and used to clear cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You can try code in this thread and follow answer of November Rain. It works for me.
[Getting all cookies from WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33156567/getting-all-cookies-from-wkwebview/34005868)

Comment: How do you get the cookies out after setting a new pool? Nevermind stupid me, read the answer carefully and referred to the other 2 answers.