# WKWebsiteDataStore vs HTTPCookieStorage

Tags: wkwebview

`WKWebsiteDataStore.default().httpCookieStore.getAllCookies` returns a different list of cookies from `HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies`. What is the difference between these two methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HTTPCookieStorage.shared` will be used with `URLSession.shared` network requests.

`WKWebsiteDataStore.default()` is used for `WKWebView` only. And the `getAllCookies` is asynchronous

Both are persistent.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not entirely correct. Persistent cookies are shared between `HTTPCookieStorage.shared` and `WKWebsiteDataStore.default()`, though the sharing is not always immediate.  Session cookies are not shared.  This behavior doesn't seem to be documented by Apple anywhere, but is clearly evident if you run some tests.  See this long thread for some related discussion:

[Getting all cookies from WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33156567/getting-all-cookies-from-wkwebview)