# How to fetch/store cookies from WKWebView in ios10?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, wkwebview, ios10

I am unable to fetch/store cookies from WKWebView in ios 10. Could you please help me to resolve this?

Comment: No impossible, señor.

Comment: @ElTomato is there any documented proof for this?

Answer (score 0):

you can try theses suggestions given in answer. It works for me, i hope it will helpful for you :)

[Getting all cookies from WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33156567/getting-all-cookies-from-wkwebview/34005868)

also you can try thin in your case [updated]

```
WKWebsiteDataStore.default().fetchDataRecords(ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes()) { records in records.forEach { record in print(record) }
```

Comment: Could you please tell me which solution used in above link

Comment: answer by November Rain

Comment: Still, my cookie array is empty

Comment: problem occur only in ios 10 or in other also

Comment: I tested in ios 13 device

Comment: WKWebsiteDataStore.default().fetchDataRecords(ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes()) { records in
            records.forEach { record in print(record) }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226224/discussion-between-bathi-and-shivam-parmar).